# Angular Send Mail + Attachment With AzureGraph API

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, sendmail, azure-ad-graph-api

can someone share an example of Angular send mail with Attachment 
I want to attach a zip file to mail.

Not getting any idea of how this "fileAttachment resource type" is working. for 
sendMail API 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/fileattachment?view=graph-rest-1.0

*code sample*

` mail = {

```
  message: {
    subject: 'Reminder',
    body: {
      contentType: 'Text',
      content: "Hi ${empl},"
    },
    toRecipients: [
      {
        emailAddress: {
          address: empl,
        }
      }
    ]
 },
 attachments : {
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
  "name": "smile",
  "contentBytes": "base64R0lGODdhEAYEAA7"
}
```

};

```
return this.http.post('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail', mail)`
```

Comment: can you show us some code that you have tried?

Comment: added @RajanSharma